# What is the optimal setup to beat Uprising (All Heroes) on Legendary?

Tags: overwatch

Looking for some tips because Legendary is a real nightmare, and would like to know the best heroes in terms of survivability as well as damage output. It seems most of the time our group fails is not the hacking part, but the payload part, as it is very easy to get rushed by all of the nullsector laser dogs.

Is there an optimal setup to beat Uprising on Legendary?

Comment: Hmm... why the -1?

Comment: Because it's largely subjective. Everyone will have different opinions.

Comment: It can be helpful to look at the scoreboard for this mode. Check the top scores (which can be attained only on legendary mode) and look at the most used heroes. As @Kaizerwolf said, it is subjective but there are some patterns in the team comps.

Comment: @Wipqozn This is not a duplicate of the question you have marked. There are two "Uprising" game modes in Overwatch at the moment: one which forces you to use a specific set of heroes (the "lore-friendly" mode) and one where you can choose any heroes. This question is about the latter; the one you marked as the dupe target is the former.

Comment: @MageXy Great, thanks for letting me know and making that more clear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bastion because his dmg is the highest in the game, and Torb is second in this mode at least. because him and his turret both do dmg so its adds up. then get Rien and and healer probably and maybe Mercy but I wouldn't recommend.

Anyway this is just built around the Bastion pretty much and the Torb is your second dps hero. play safe behind Rien and he has to be care full to not just hold shield up and use it more so when it is actually needed. the healer is for the rest.

Comment: I also really recommand using Zen. His orb of discord really eases the pain of the ennemy bastions and the giant bombs. It makes a great synergy with your bastion (mercy damage boost also works but is not as efficient). If you look at the top scores for this mode you'll see that zen is used a lot. Not to forget that his ult can save a desperate situation.